# What the is the meaning of "question mark" in classifier output in WEKA?

Tags: weka

I want to know what is the meaning of the "question mark" in === Detailed Accuracy By Class === when I use the Classifier Output in WEKA. My dataset is Fertility Dataset. Does this " question mark" influence the tree?
Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A `?` in the output means that the result (value) is mathematically *undefined*. This might arise from a *division by zero*, for instance.

*Source*: See [here](https://weka.8497.n7.nabble.com/in-the-detailed-accuracy-by-class-td45743.html).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

As written by @MWiesner, ? is the Weka representation of Nan.

Just to add to his answer, this means that you propably have division by zero when calculating some evaluation metrics.

This means that your dataset doesn't have enough samples to perform a reliable classification (at least for the O class). If there were enough data, it would have to be really unlucky (or your features would have the be really poor) to get a ? result.

So my suggestion here is to add more instances. If you are working with image classification for example, try to use data-augmentation through rotation for example.